# Use custom formatting to offset text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

How can I offset a text in my cell if it contains a specific value, without adding new caractéres ?

I would like something **like** a tabulation before my text if it contain (lvl 1) and two tabuation if it contain (lvl 2) ...

I'm specificaly looking for a custom formatting to apply to a text but I'm open to any other solution.

Comment: Show few input and output.

Comment: Have you had a look to `indentLevel`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.indentlevel